# function return with custom defined managed class type

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

I meet a problem when I'm using C++/CLI.
I defined a class called Person, it's a simple class with gets and sets:
    #pragma once
    using namespace System;

```
namespace CLI
{
    public ref class Person
    {
    public:
        Person();
        // gets and sets
    private:
        String^ name;
        int age;
    };
}
```

Then I defined a matrix class with person:
    #pragma once
    #include "Person.h"
    using namespace System;

```
namespace CLI
{
    // Next is the managed wrapper of Logic:
    public ref class Matrix
    {
    public:
        Matrix();
        Person^ getPerson(int i, int j)
        {
            return paa[i][j]; // no problem
        }
        void Destroy();
    private:
        array<array<Person^>^>^ paa;
    };
}
```

It's very strange that if I move getPerson() function to .cpp, there will be errors.

Here is the Matrix.h & Matrix.cpp with errors:

```
// Matrix.h
#pragma once
#include "Person.h"
using namespace System;

namespace CLI
{
    public ref class Matrix
    {
    public:
        Matrix();
        Person^ getPerson(int i, int j);
        void Destroy();
    private:
        array<array<Person^>^>^ paa;
    };
}


// Matrix.cpp
#include "Matrix.h"

CLI::Matrix::Matrix()
{
    // init the matrix
}

Person^ CLI::Matrix::getPerson(int i, int j) // errors here
{
    return paa[i][j];
}
```

One of errors says "Undefined identifier: Person", and this error is point to the function return type. I tried to write "Person^ p = gcnew Person;" in the function body, there was no error.
Another error says "The function definition is not compatible with the one in .h file"(I'm not using English version of VS, I translated the  message, may be not very accurate.)

If I change the return type anything not custom defined, like int, String^, it's OK.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the error, not the code that doesn't.

Comment: @DavidYaw I edited, I gave the code with errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
Person^ CLI::Matrix::getPerson(int i, int j)
```

Class `Person` is defined within the `CLI` namespace, but you're not referencing that namespace here.

You're not getting an error message in the header file because the declaration is contained in a `namespace CLI { }` block, and the cpp file doesn't have that.

To fix this, I recommend that you enclose all of the code in your cpp file inside a `namespace CLI { }` block, and remove the `CLI::` from the various declarations. I think this looks cleaner than the other solution, which is to fully-qualify the return type (`CLI::Person^`).